# Class instances in console application

Tags: java, console-application

I'm working on a simple console application but i suddenly noticed a gap in my "knowledge" of classes.

I have a main java file and a separate class - "Account"

I wanted to create a new instance of account from a "Register Account" method. Without thinking about it i wrote the following and moved on.

```
Account newAcc = new Account();
```

But now I realize that i have no idea how to access the new Account or any further Account instances. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Thanks!

EDIT: more code

```
newAcc = new Account();
newAcc.name = "my name";
newAcc.balance = 0;

//Later i do this:
newAcc = new Account();
newAcc.name = "your name";
newAcc.balance = 1000;
```

Now I want to know "my" balance?

Comment: You usually access the methods within a class via the object you created...so `newAcc.someMethod()`.

Comment: for example int balance = newAcc.getBalance()  .....assuming you have a getBalance method in the class that returns an int

Comment: I'm wondering what happens if i reassign the variable newAcc to a new Account instance, can i access the separate instances in some way other than the variable name, or do i essentially destroy the previous instances of Account

Comment: When you reassign a value, it will forget the old value, and reference the new one. If nothing references the old value, it will be eligible for deletion from memory by the garbage collector.

Comment: I added some more code, hope it clarifies what i'm trying to do

Comment: If you want to keep track of two separate `Account` instances then you need either separate variables for their references or some kind of collective holder, such as an array or a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the two `Account` objects in different variables.

```
Account myAcc = new Account();
myAcc.name = "my name";
myAcc.balance = 0;

//Later i do this:
Account yourAcc = new Account();
yourAcc.name = "your name";
yourAcc.balance = 1000;
```

If you store them both in `myAcc`, when you create a new one the old one will be overwritten.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then if I want to create a method that makes new Accounts I guess I'm best off using an array